# Moving a windows form without a status bar, borderstyle

Tags: c#

I have the following line that removes all borders from my window forms.  Is it possible to drag the form to a different part of the screen.  For example by adding some sort of hidden bar the stop from which I would be able to drag?

Here is the code I use to hide the borders

```
  this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms - Click/drag anywhere in the form to move it as if clicked in the form caption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184/winforms-click-drag-anywhere-in-the-form-to-move-it-as-if-clicked-in-the-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11114/Move-window-form-without-Titlebar-in-C